# Segmentation fault while copying string to a char array using memcpy

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, memcpy

I want to store a string in char array I am trying to do so by using a `memcpy()` but I am getting a `segmentation fault`. Can someone explain why? And what could be the correct way of doing this.

What would be better to use `char * name;` or  `char name[100];` ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A
{
 char * name;

};

typedef struct A A ;

int main()
{

    A *a;

    memcpy(a->name,"hello",sizeof(A));
    printf("The value of name is %s",a->name);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: try printf(sizeof(A))

Comment: You haven't allocated any memory for `a` to point to. The same applies to `a->name`. You need to allocate memory for both.

Comment: Neither of your pointers `a` and `a->name` point somewhere reasonable.

Comment: You might like the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/), especially section 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to allocate memory for structure and it's member and then after you can do copy data in it.

```
A *a = malloc(sizeof(A));
a->name=malloc(100); //change the size other then 100 what ever you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

In first place you are asking two questions. You should read a bit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to understand how to ask good questions and get good answers.

You get segmentation fault because you haven't allocated memory for you variable `name`. The fastest way to solve this according the code and description you have provided is to use `char name[100]` in your declaration. Bear in mind that this is not the only possible way to do things. It depends what you are doing.

```
struct A
{
  char name[100];
};
```

Then you have to allocate memory for the `A *a` pointer you are declaring. Better would be to use a normal variable `A a` and then access the member with the point operator (not sure if that is really an operator but the correct words doesn't come to mind at the moment). A simple snippet would be:

```
...
A a;
memcpy(a.name, "hello", 6);
printf("The value of name is %s",a.name);
...
```

A bit of documentation doesn't harm: [memcpy()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy)